# is it allowed to rerun your entire predictive model?

Tags: r, machine-learning

Hi i am new to r and I have made a predictive model for the iris dataset (using the multinom function from the package nnet).

When i ran the model for the first time I got an accuracy score 0f 0.9667, but when i rerun the (entire) same code I am getting different accuracy scores (0.933, 0,9667 and 1).

Because of this occurance I think that i might be violating some rules of machine learning.

My questions are:
- Is it allowed to rerun your model?
- Why do i get different accuracy scores for the same code?

```
#set random seed
set.seed(42)

#shuffle run indices dataset
rows <- sample(nrow(iris))

# use the random vector to reorder the iris dataset
iris <- iris[rows,]


#80 20 split
#split point approximately 80% through the data
split <- round(nrow(iris) * 0.80)

# use first 80 % for training
training <- iris[1:split, ]

#use other 20 % for testing
test <- iris[(split+1):nrow(iris),]

#make model
model <- multinom(formula = Species ~ ., data = training)
p <- predict(model, test)

# create confusion matrix
(results <- confusionMatrix(data = p, reference = test$Species))
```

Answer (score 1):

it is always good to set the seed first before running any predictive model. Set the seed as you wish before starting the model and check result will be same

Comment: Is it better to run the model many times with many seeds, and be guided by the average outcome?

Comment: the code already included set.seed. I have edited my question so that it includes the code.

Comment: I think its because you are rerunning the code with each rerun using the updated iris data-frame from the run before (iris <- iris[rows,]).
Include a rm(list = ls()) just after your set.seed and you should get the same predictions over time as long as you keep the seed the same.

Comment: the rm(list = ls()) worked! Could you explain how adding this command solves the problem? I know rm(list = ls()) removes everything from the global enviroment, but I don't understand why i do get the same prediction over time with the command and that i don't get the same predictions when i don't use rm(list = ls())

Comment: I think its the order R looks for objects. When you first run the command iris <- iris[rows,] a data.frame iris is stored in your workspace. Next time you run the comand R just looks for the object iris and since there is one in workspace allready it is used (instead of the original iris from the datasets). If you clear the workspace first there is no iris object yet. If you change this iris <- iris[rows,] to iris2 <- iris[rows,] it should work as well without clearing
the workspace (the name doesn't have to be iris2. It can be anything thats not exactly iris).